# Google sign in "Choose an account to continue" loop

Tags: android, flutter, google-fit, google-developers-console, google-fit-api

I'm trying to implement the following packages with my Flutter app:

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

https://pub.dev/packages/fit_kit

and I've done so by writing the following two functions:

```
Future<void> checkPermissions() async {
 var status = await Permission.activityRecognition.status;
 if (status.isUndetermined || status.isDenied) {
   Permission.activityRecognition.request();
}  else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
   openAppSettings();
 }
}

Future<void> read() async {
 results.clear();
 await checkPermissions();
 for (DataType type in [DataType.STEP_COUNT, DataType.DISTANCE]) {
   try {
     results[type] = await FitKit.read(
       type,
       dateFrom: _weekBeginning,
       dateTo: _now,
     );
   } on UnsupportedException catch (e) {
     results[e.dataType] = [];
   }
 }
 dailyStepBuffer = 0;
 dailyDistanceBuffer = 0;
 for(FitData dataPoint in results[DataType.STEP_COUNT]){
   print(dataPoint);
   dailyStepBuffer += dataPoint.value.round();
 }
 for(FitData dataPoint in results[DataType.DISTANCE]){
   print(dataPoint);
   dailyDistanceBuffer += dataPoint.value.round();
 }
 setState(() {
   dailySteps = dailyStepBuffer;
   dailyDistance = dailyDistanceBuffer;
 });
}
```

The functions and packages work as intended on iOS, but for some reason, whenever I call read() on an Android device, [it shows me this sign in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9LVe.png), and when I click on my account, it does nothing and I get the error:

`E/flutter ( 8211): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(FitKit, User denied permission access, null)`

I've gotten the OAuth 2.0 client ID using my SHA-1 fingerprint, added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>` to my AndroidManifest.xml file and added the following to my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
```

Unfortunately though, none of these appear to have solved the issue. I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could help me solve this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that for some reason, my package name and application id were different, and so entering the application id instead of the package name when getting my OAuth 2.0 Client ID solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `flutter clean` and check if this persist?

Comment: Ran ```flutter clean``` and unfortunately the issue persists

Comment: Does the phone you're testing on support google fit? Can you try another device?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but fortunately I managed to solve the issue. Thanks for the assistance though Ahmed, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the FitKit class has a `requestPermissions` method. Use that along with `FitKit.hasPermissions` to ensure that the necessary permissions are granted.

Comment: I've now implemented requestPermissions and hasPermissions, and unfortunately the issue persists